# Alias method in QML component

Tags: qt, qml

In QML, I am writing a component like so:

```qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import NDDQuickItem 1.0

Item {
  property alias source: ndd.nddContentPath

  function goToSlide(component,slide){
    ndd.goToSlide(component,slide);
  }

  NDDQuickItem {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    id: ndd
  }
}
```

I can use `property alias` to "promote" properties of the `NDDQuickItem` to the root of the component. However, as shown, I'm currently writing component-global methods that just re-call a method on the `NDDQuickItem`.

Is there an equivalent to `property alias` that works for methods? Something like:

```
method alias goToSlide: ndd.goToSlide // not valid QML
```

or

```
goToSlide = ndd.goToSlide             // not valid QML
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not using `alias`, but you can `property var v : someId.someFoo` and then you can `object.v()`.

Note that if `someFoo() { console.log(this) }`, then in `someId.someFoo()` `this` will be `someId`, while in `object.v()` `this` will be `object`. That will not be a problem when referencing stuff in the function body due to how JS works, nothing like having the wrong `this` in C++.

You could also use a signal:

```
signal goToSlide(var component,int slide)
onGoToSlide: ndd.goToSlide(component,slide)
```

With the added benefit you can "remap" it to something else, from outside the component.

At any rate, both are not really necessary:

> I'm currently writing global methods that just re-call a method on the
>   NDDQuickItem.

It is not global, it is a member of the root object, and there is nothing wrong with doing that, it is common practice. I mean if efficiency is a primary concern, you wouldn't be writing QML. Also, know that `alias` doesn't come for free either, in the case of ints and reals, it takes pretty much the same space as a full fledged property would.

Comment: Nice. Interesting note on the scoping of `this`, thanks!

Comment: You're right about 'global', I was sloppy in my language. I've edited it ("component-global"). I'm not so much trying to micro-optimize as I am trying to simplify the signatures and argument passing, and more clearly show that the method is just an "alias" and not any extra functionality beyond the pass through.

Comment: It's OK like that IMO, not any more nonsensical than writing accessor functions for a private member in C++